# Separating Angular Material cards vertically

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, ngfor

I want to list items in an array vertically with cards, but there is no space between them. I tried to use padding but it seems it doesn't work.

[card image](https://ibb.co/eXtg7e)

How can I have these cards spaced?

```
<ng-container *ngIf="titles?.length; else noTitle">
    <mat-card class="asd cardPardding" *ngFor="let title of titles">
      <p>
      {{title}}
      </p>
    </mat-card>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #noTitle>
    <mat-card class="asd cardPardding">
      <p>
      No title !
      </p>
  </mat-card>
  </ng-template>
```

This is css

```
.asd {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto; /* Added */
}

.inputasd {
  width: 100%;
}

.cardPadding {
  padding: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `margin-bottom: 10px;`

Comment: I tried, it should work but It doesn't.

Comment: Are you applying the property to the right element? `mat-card { margin-bottom: 10px; }`

Comment: I was applying the property to right element but wrong class name. This was my mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> .component.html

```
<ng-container *ngIf="titles?.length; else noTitle">
    <mat-card class="my-class-name asd cardPardding" *ngFor="let title of titles">
        <p>
            {{title}}
        </p>
    </mat-card>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #noTitle>
    <mat-card class="asd cardPardding">
        <p>
            No title !
        </p>
    </mat-card>
</ng-template>
```

> .css/.scss file

```
.my-class-name{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    ... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent too much time to fix this. Then I thought I know something wrong but my mistake was only 1 letter in the class name. You all right, margin works. I typed class name wrong. Thanks for the response.